# C# WPF specify folders in XAML style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Proj
├──Views
├   ├──Dashboard.xaml
├   ├──Dashboard.cs
├
├──Styles
    ├──DashboardStyle.xaml
```

In my `DashboardStyle.xaml`, I have this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proj.Styles">

    <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="local:Proj/Views/Dashboard">
        ....
        ....
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But it gives the error:

> The name "Proj/Views/Dashboard" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Proj.Styles"

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't `local` be `clr-namespace:Proj.Views`? And then the `TargetType` becomes `local:Dashboard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are referenced using namepace and type name, not via physical file paths.

So to reference the type `Proj.Views.Dashboard`, add the corresponding namespace as XML namespace declaration and use it in the TargetType attribute, e.g.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proj.Styles"
                xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Proj.Views" >

    <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="views:Dashboard">
        ....
        ....
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: but i'm having another problem now...i also have titlebar buttons style  `<Style x:Key="WindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">` in the same file. the buttons are getting the style, but not changing color on hover, or working on click

Comment: For another problem, please ask another question.